# xatom-debugger connect to remote node inspector

Tags: javascript, node.js, atom-editor, node-inspector

I'm trying to debug my app remotely with node inspector on remote server and xatom debugger on client.

What I've done on server side:

```
node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 ./lib/index.js
```

On client side:

```
ssh -L 9229:localhost:9229 me@myserver.net //to redirect port
```

[image]

but I've recieved the following error message:

```
XAtom Debug: Unable to map file
```

notwithstanding I have all map files I need (compiled by tsc)